# How to get the current token of java editor in a plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, editor, token

How do I programmatically get a current token on which there is a caret in a java editor in Eclipse plugin?  For example, if the caret is placed on one of characters of a string (say, "text here") I would like to get 'text here' as a value in a eclipse plugin. Is there API for that? I have found an example to get a highlighted selection, but could not find to one that calculates the current token just by offset of the caret.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
IEditorPart editor = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor();
```

to get the current active editor.

Then do (after checking that the editorpart is a ITextEditor)

```
IDocumentProvider provider = ((ITextEditor) editor).getDocumentProvider();
IDocument document = provider.getDocument(((ITextEditor) editor).getEditorInput());
ITextSelection textSelection = (ITextSelection) ((ITextEditor) editor).getSite().getSelectionProvider().getSelection();

int offset = textSelection.getOffset();
int lineNumber = document.getLineOfOffset(offset);
```

to get the offset and line number, and you could use this information to parse out the relevant text/token from the document. This will work even if no text is selected (i.e. the caret position).